# [movie-rating]: star ratings vs. MPAA/content ratings

Tags: discussion, tags

There appears to be some overlap in the use of the [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) tag with some users using it for *content ratings* (as in MPAA rating/content certification) while others are using it for questions on *star ratings* (as in IMDb and critic rating). The tag's wiki states that it is to be used for content ratings.

How can this ambiguity be resolved?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use an unambiguous tag such as [age-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-rating) which cannot be misinterpreted as a tag about the quality or people's opinion of the movie? The MPAA and the BBFC, for example, base most of their rating judgements on what is appropriate for a particular age range (thought the MPAA is a good deal less clear and more annoying than the BBFC).

The tag [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating) is inevitably ambiguous and will only be understood by those who read the full tag explanation (and so is likely to be missed by some however you define it). Replace it with an unambiguous term and deprecate the old usage.

Comment: I agree with you. I think [tag:age-rating] and just [tag:rating] or [tag:review] for ratings in terms of IMDb ratings would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It can only be resolved by us actively editing the questions and separating the meanings - perhaps creating a [censorship](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship) tag for MPAA (or other national censoring organization) questions.

Comment: That tag already exists and is used for a different purpose. I'm not sure if "content rating" is really censorship, though. Could _star ratings_ be squeezed into a _review_ or _review-system_ tag?

Comment: @coleopterist - I struggled with using that word too, in the UK the BBFC was originally a censoring organization, but nowadays just classifies and relies on the producers of the movie to cut to achieve a desired classification.  I settled on censorship as classification is a rather technical term - censorship would have a broader immediate recognition.  Still recognize the problems with the term.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, its quite hard to discuss this across several days with several people.  I'm going to create this answer and encourage people to comment and edit to arrive at collections of synonymous tags.   Suggested lead tag shown first:

Please add or remove or re-group these - but please add comments as you do so, so people can see your argument and return them if there is disagreement.  I've started with a suggestion, but honestly I'm not that enamored of [movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating).

**Meaning: classification or certification of a movie by some national or regional body, e.g. MPAA, BBFC, CBFC:**

[content-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-rating): [age-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-rating), [classification](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), [certification](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certification)

**Meaning: a system of reviewing the quality of a movie through numeric score, stars or similar:**

[movie-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-rating): [star-review](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-review), [rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rating), [review-system](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-system)